# PostGIS finding all circles containing a specific point - how to define an index

Tags: postgresql, gis, postgis

I want to find all points which are not farther than a point specific distance away from a given point. Like a normal radius search, only the radius is variable with each point (Each entry is defining a circle around itself using a point + radius).

The question I have is how to define an index for this problem (the query I use at the moment is below), also if it is possible to create an index using non GIS and GIS fields (like the Enable field below).

I currently have this working query for it

```
SELECT "Locations"."Name",
FROM public."Locations"
WHERE
    "Locations"."Enabled" = TRUE
    AND ST_DWithin(
        "Locations"."MyCoord"::geography,
        ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(<Given Long>, <Given Lat>),4326)::geography,
        "Locations"."Radius");
```

with a table like the following

```
Id: uuid
Name: text
Enabled: boolean
MyCoord: GEOGRAPHY(Point)
Radius: double precision
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Create index some_name_idx on public."Locations" using gist("MyCoord")
```

But you have a BUG - there is no such function ST_DWithin(geometry,geography,numeric) - if you have radius in meters use geography in both cases, so you don't need a conversion (also in index)

---

EDIT:

Don't worry - it'll work, I checked it... as a proof, I've got a table planet_osm_point created by osm2pgsql with index:

```
CREATE INDEX planet_osm_point_index
  ON planet_osm_point
  USING gist
  (way);
```

And I'm running a query like yours:

```
explain select * 
from planet_osm_point 
where st_dwithin(way,ST_geomfromtext('POINT(2219360.7 6457010.96)'),300)
```

Output is [here](https://explain.depesz.com/s/Cjrs). 
As you see spatial index is in use...

Comment: This was an copy and paste error, both a geography. But how can the index on just MyCoord (which is the center of the circle around it) speed up the search if the radius is not used in the index at all (AFAIK at least a bounding box is needed to speed up the search).

Comment: The subtle difference i see in you query is that you have a static distance to check for, but in my query the distance as well as one coordinate is in the queried table. So your query has just one variable element and mine has two.

Comment: Did you checked it? This element is also a variable which I thinked out after index was made... There is no difference. As you see there is no 300 in index definition...